# preserving local accounts during AD installation

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, timezone

We have a Windows 2008 R2 server with about 50 local accounts (no AD).  The server functions as a terminal server for users around the world.  We have been having issues with the time zones for users that are outside the country.  Someone told me that AD will allow time zone redirection, so we are considering installing that.

My first question is will there be a way to preserve the user accounts, passwords and groups after the AD install?  I have seen something called the Windows Server Migration Tool that supposedly will do this - has anyone ever used this and does it work?

Secondly, is AD totally necessary for this?  Does anyone know if there is a way to do time zone redirects without AD?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, AD is not neccessary. You can configure the local Group Policy to allow time zone redirection. This is a computer setting so this will affect all users logging in to the server via RDS.

Open an MMC console, add the Group Policy Object Editor snapin, focused on the local computer, expand Computer Configuration|Administrative Templates|Windows Components|Remote Desktop Services|Remote Desktop Session Host|Device and Resource Redirection and enable the "Allow time zone redirection" group policy setting.

Comment: Just a note if you or anyone else is looking at AD and comes across this question you only lose the local account on the domain controller(s). Every member server can have local accounts.

Comment: Glad to help...